# Reindexing a pandas series with a set of strings is removing the orignial data in the series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series called day_counts, which would normally contain 7 values, but can look something like this. 0 corresponds to monday up to 6, the sunday.

```
Name: dow, dtype: int64
0    332
1    722
2    721
```

However the index needs to be 7 values long (for days of the week), so I reindex the series, but use a list of string as the index. The code is shown below (_scrobbles is a dataframe read from a csv file):

```
_scrobbles = self.scrobbles.query('month == ' + str(self.month))
_scrobbles['text_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(_scrobbles['text_timestamp'])
_scrobbles['dow'] = _scrobbles['text_timestamp'].map(lambda x: x.weekday())
data = _scrobbles['dow'].value_counts().sort_index()
day_counts = pd.Series(data=data)
new_index = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
day_counts_new = day_counts.reindex(index=new_index, fill_value=0)
```

This creates the new index, but any existing data is overwirtten by a 0, outputting this:

```
Mon    0
Tue    0
Wed    0
Thu    0
Fri    0
Sat    0
Sun    0
Name: dow, dtype: int64
```

It should look like this

```
Mon    332
Tue    722
Wed    721
Thu    0
Fri    0
Sat    0
Sun    0
```

Does anyone know how I can keep the existing data?

Whats interesing is if I set the index as just numbers like so `new_index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Then it works as intended

Thanks

Comment: In your day_counts what does zero stands for 'Monday'? What is the correspondence between the old index and the new index?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of how `dow` is created.

Comment: Yes sorry, the 0 is a monday up to 6, the sunday. For example if I reindex, but just use a list of numbers, the data stays in the right posistion, i.e right weekday, and all the others are set to 0, also included the full code of how dow is created, updated in the main post

Comment: I believe it works with numbers because pandas knows what is the correspondence between the new index and the old index, using the week day name have no correspondence with 0, 1, 2 ...

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense I guess, is there anyway to keep that correspondence? For example set_index would work, except in the cases where there are not 7 peices of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this problem by creating dictionary and zipping a list of weekdays, to the initial series, and then creating a dataframe from the dictionary.

```
hour_counts = _scrobbles['dow'].value_counts().sort_index() 
days = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun'.split()
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dict(zip(days, hour_counts)).items()), columns=['Month', 'Count'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([332,722,721,0,0,0,0])
>>> df
     0
0  332
1  722
2  721
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
>>> new_index = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
>>> df.set_index(pd.Series(new_index))
       0
Mon  332
Tue  722
Wed  721
Thu    0
Fri    0
Sat    0
Sun    0
```

Just make sure your initial dataframe has the same length as your `new_index`. But as you say in the opening of your post; it normally contains 7 values so no worries there.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have:

- `day_counts`, e.g. `pd.Series([ 332, 722, 721 ])`
- `new_index = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']`

To create the result, start from a *Series* containing 7 zeroes:

```
dc = pd.Series(7 * [0])
```

Then update it with `day_counts`:

```
dc.update(day_counts)
```

The result is that you have a Series containing 7 items, initial items
from `day_counts` and remaining items = 0.

Then just substitute the index in `dc` with `new_index`:

```
dc.index = new_index
```

The result is:

```
Mon    332
Tue    722
Wed    721
Thu      0
Fri      0
Sat      0
Sun      0
```

### Edit

Please find below a little changed solution of the whole issue,
based on `groupby`, even without any auxiliary table and updating:

```
import pandas as pd

# Source data
df = pd.DataFrame([ '2018-12-01', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-01' ],
    columns=['text_timestamp'])
# Change dates from string to datetime
df.text_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.text_timestamp)
# Add dow column
df['dow'] = df.text_timestamp.dt.dayofweek
# Compute day counts
day_counts = df.groupby('dow')['text_timestamp'].count()\
    .reindex(range(0, 7), fill_value=0)
# Change index
day_counts.index = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
```

For the above data, the result is:

```
Mon    1
Tue    0
Wed    0
Thu    0
Fri    0
Sat    2
Sun    1
```

Comment: Thank you, ive tested this, and this does also work, however im going to keep the method I posted below as it is now working as I would like